# How to pass parameters in DataTables.Editable sUpdateURL

Tags: datatables

Hi I need to pass parameters in DataTables.Editable sUpdateURL, I have tried

```
.makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: "test/list/Delay.do?,
        oUpdateParameters: {
                "testId": "a1" 
        },
        "aoColumns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                    {
                      cssclass: "required digits",
                       onblur: 'submit'
                    },
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
        ]   
    });
```

But it doesn't work. I don't want to pass along with the url. I Am using jQuery datattable 1.9.4 and spring mvc.

Comment: What version of jquery datatables are you using? If you updated to a newer version you could use http://editor.datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Comment: @Hofan thanks for your quick reply , am using datattable 1.9.4

Comment: can anyone please help..

Comment: Can you put a working example on jsfiddle? oUpdateParameters should work if you followed the tutorial here: http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit-parameters.html

Comment: tried something like this `sUpdateUrl:"xyz/x?testid="+"hello"` . share us more code so we can see whats going on

Comment: @super cool..Thanks for your comment..I have already tried this..But I don't want to pass paramters like this.

Comment: can anyone please help to solve this..I have been trying all I can on this from the last one week..but None of them worked well.. :(